# Showing time according to different time zones in Analog Clock

Tags: android, time, clock

I have two analog clocks in my application. One clock will display the current location time. Another clock will be used for showing the time of different time zones that are selected by the user.
  I am used the following code to setting the particular timezone to the second clock. But it is not working properly. Can anyone please help me.

```
public class ClockWidgetDemo extends Activity {
MyAnalogClock clock2;
TimePicker timePicker;
Time timeSetter;
Button btn;
 String timezone = "America/Los_Angeles";
 String time;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
 //TimeZone time=TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone);
    time=sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.i("Analog Clock", "Time"+sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             //timeSetter=new Time(time);
             timeSetter=new Time(timezone);

            onTimeChanged();



        }
    });
clock2 = (MyAnalogClock) findViewById(R.id.clock2);
    public void onTimeChanged(){



    timeSetter.set(timeSetter.second,timeSetter.minute,timeSetter.HOUR,timeSetter.monthDay, timeSetter.month, timeSetter.year);

    Log.i("Analog Clock","Seconds"+timeSetter.second+"Minute"+timeSetter.minute+"Hour"+timeSetter.hour+"Month Day"
            +timeSetter.monthDay+"Month"+timeSetter.month+"Year"+timeSetter.year);

    clock2.setTime(timeSetter.toMillis(true));

}
}
```

And my Analog clock  code is

```
public class MyAnalogClock extends View{
public MyAnalogClock(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private Time mCalendar;

private Drawable mHourHand;
private Drawable mMinuteHand;
private Drawable mSecondHand;
private Drawable mDial;

private int mDialWidth;
private int mDialHeight;

private boolean mAttached;

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private float mMinutes;
private float mHour;
private boolean mChanged;

Context mContext;

public MyAnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MyAnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Resources r = context.getResources();

//      TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AnalogClock, defStyle, 0);
    mContext = context;
    // mDial =
    // a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_dial);
    // if (mDial == null) {
    mDial = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_dial1);
    // }

    // mHourHand =
    // a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_hour);
    // if (mHourHand == null) {
    mHourHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_hour);
    // }

    // mMinuteHand =
    // a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_minute);
    // if (mMinuteHand == null) {
    mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_minute);
    mSecondHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clockgoog_minute);
    // }

    mCalendar = new Time();

    mDialWidth = mDial.getIntrinsicWidth();
    mDialHeight = mDial.getIntrinsicHeight();
}



    @Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (!mAttached) {
        mAttached = true;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);

        getContext().registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null,
                mHandler);
    }

    // NOTE: It's safe to do these after registering the receiver since the
    // receiver always runs
    // in the main thread, therefore the receiver can't run before this
    // method returns.

    // The time zone may have changed while the receiver wasn't registered,
    // so update the Time
    mCalendar = new Time();

    // Make sure we update to the current time
    onTimeChanged();
    counter.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    if (mAttached) {
        counter.cancel();
        getContext().unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
        mAttached = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    float hScale = 1.0f;
    float vScale = 1.0f;

    if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && widthSize < mDialWidth) {
        hScale = (float) widthSize / (float) mDialWidth;
    }

    if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && heightSize < mDialHeight) {
        vScale = (float) heightSize / (float) mDialHeight;
    }

    float scale = Math.min(hScale, vScale);

    setMeasuredDimension(
            resolveSize((int) (mDialWidth * scale), widthMeasureSpec),
            resolveSize((int) (mDialHeight * scale), heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mChanged = true;
}


protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    boolean changed = mChanged;
    if (changed) {
        mChanged = false;
    }
    boolean seconds = mSeconds;
    if (seconds) {
        mSeconds = false;
    }
    int availableWidth = 200;
    int availableHeight = 200;

    int x = availableWidth / 2;
    int y = availableHeight / 2;

    final Drawable dial = mDial;
    int w = dial.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int h = dial.getIntrinsicHeight();

    boolean scaled = false;

    if (availableWidth < w || availableHeight < h) {
        scaled = true;
        float scale = Math.min((float) availableWidth / (float) w,
                (float) availableHeight / (float) h);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scale, scale, x, y);
    }

    if (changed) {
        dial.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
    }
    dial.draw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(mHour / 12.0f * 360.0f, x, y);
    final Drawable hourHand = mHourHand;
    if (changed) {
        w = hourHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
        h = hourHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
        hourHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y
                + (h / 2));
    }
    hourHand.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(mMinutes / 60.0f * 360.0f, x, y);
    // canvas.rotate(mSecond, x, y);
    final Drawable minuteHand = mMinuteHand;
    if (changed) {
        w = minuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
        h = minuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
        minuteHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y
                + (h / 2));
    }
    minuteHand.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(mSecond, x, y);

    // minuteHand = mMinuteHand;
    if (seconds) {
        w = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
        h = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mSecondHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y
                + (h / 2));
    }
    mSecondHand.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    if (scaled) {
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

MyCount counter = new MyCount(10000, 1000);

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        counter.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mCalendar.set(System.currentTimeMillis() - 60000);

          //            int hour = mCalendar.hour;
          //            int minute = mCalendar.minute;
        int second = mCalendar.second;

        mSecond = 6.0f * second;
        mSeconds = true;
        // mChanged = true;
        MyAnalogClock.this.invalidate();
        // Toast.makeText(mContext, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void setOffset(long offset){
    this.offset = offset;
    onTimeChanged();
}

public void setTime(long time){
    long tmp = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    this.offset = tmp;
    onTimeChanged();
}

boolean mSeconds = false;
float mSecond = 0;
long offset = 0;

private void onTimeChanged() {
    mCalendar.set(System.currentTimeMillis() - offset);

    int hour = mCalendar.hour;
    int minute = mCalendar.minute;
    int second = mCalendar.second;

    mMinutes = minute + second / 60.0f;
    mHour = hour + mMinutes / 60.0f;
    mChanged = true;
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
            String tz = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone");
            mCalendar = new Time(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz).getID());
        }

        onTimeChanged();

        invalidate();
    }
};


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Code to get Different Time Zone Date and Time.

```
private Date getDateInTimeZone(Date currentDate, String timeZoneId) 
{
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId);
    Calendar mbCal = new GregorianCalendar(tz);
    mbCal.setTimeInMillis(currentDate.getTime());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mbCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mbCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mbCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mbCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mbCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, mbCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, mbCal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    return cal.getTime();
 }

String tz = "America/Los_Angeles";
Date date = new Date();
date = getDateInTimeZone(date, tz);
```

Comment: hi i am used in this way. But it is not working properly. It is displaying the correct time but i am passing that time into timesetter it is showing wrong time in the clock.

Comment: In my button onclick i have used the following code to set time to clock. cdate=getDateInTimeZone(cdate, timezone);
    zonetime=sdf1.format(cal.getTime());
    Log.i("Analog Clock","Zone Return Time"+zonetime);
     
    timeSetter=new Time(zonetime);
        onTimeChanged();

Comment: then i think there is some problem in set time in clock